# Show compactness and totally boundedness for metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Im trying to prove compactness and totally boundedness for the given (see 1 and 2 ) sets. I would be thankful if someone could comfirm if I did it correct and if not, show how I can accomplish it. Appreciating all help!

**1) Use the definition of compactness to show that the set $K = \{0\} \cup \{2^{-n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is compact.**

My attempt:

Let $\{G_\lambda\}_\Lambda$ be an open cover of K (that is $K\subset \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}G_\lambda$) and assume $ 0 \in  G_{\lambda_{0}}$. Then $\exists \varepsilon >0$ s.t. $B(0,\epsilon) \subset G_{\lambda_0}$ (since $G_{\lambda_0}$ is open). Since $\varepsilon < \infty$ there exists a $N$ s.t. $2^{-N} < \varepsilon$ and thus, we have that $2^{-n} \in  B(0,\varepsilon)$ for all $n> N$.

Now let $2^{-m} \in G_{\lambda_m}$ for $1 \leq m \leq N$. Then we have that $K \subset \bigcup_{m=1}^N G_{\lambda_m}\cup G_{\lambda_0}$, that is,  we have a finite subcover for ever open cover of $K$. By definition, $K$ is compact.

**2)
Show that  $K$ \ $\{0\} =  \{2^{-n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ can be covered by finitely many balls with radius $\varepsilon$**.

My attempt:

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $N$ s.t. $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$. Then we have $ K \subset \bigcup _{i=1}^{n}B(2^{-i}, \frac{1}{N})$ and we are done.

Comment: For 2), what is $n$ (the upper bound) in your reunion of balls supposedly covering $K$? 1) looks correct.

Comment: @Mindlack sorry but I'm not sure I'm following... n is an arbitrary natural number and I'm supposed to show that the set can be covered by finitely many balls (totally boundedness)

Comment: as written, $n$ isn’t arbitrary, it’s undefined there (not all $n$ will work). Which finite cover do you choose if, say, $\epsilon=0.1$ and $N=11$?

Comment: @Mindlack I believe I understand what you mean now. But I can't see how to choose a radius only dependant of epsilon,  but still incorperate the dependancy of n... thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

1 is correct ( a neighbourhood containing $0$ contains all but finitely many of the rest of the points etc. )

2 directly follows as $K$ is compact and so totally bounded and subsets of totally bounded sets still are totally bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I'm trying to answer each question by itself (from definition) and not as a result from one or another.